# 403 Access denied on My Single Page

Tags: http-status-code-403

I have looked at the various questions related to my question but haven't found any working answers
I have created a website,
All other directories are working perfectly.
But when I access this page: http://www.pakdostana.paks.pk/private-chat it says

#### 403 access denied

All other pages are working,
My file permissions are 644 and I also try changing them to 755 and 777 but the error is same.
And I am using my own routing system.

## Updated

I have an update when I directly access the folder with this URL: http://www.pakdostana.paks.pk/Chat/Private-Chat.php it works, but not with PHP routing system what can be error any guess!
Can anyone help me!
Best regards

Comment: So, what exactly does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Nothing to do with php!

Comment: Could you give me the different directories which are working? I would like to help you

Comment: I have too many other directories and the permissions of all folders are some, other are working but this is not working one the the working url: http://www.pakdostana.paks.pk/settings

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the files permissions. You need permissions for the folder containing these files. The recommended permissions are 664 for files and 775 for folders.

As you don't specify which http server you are using nor the OS, I'm going to put an example  Apache on linux.

```
cd /var/www/
sudo chgrp -R www-data html
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

What this does is:

1. Put you on the parent directory of default Apache's base path.
2. Change group ownership recursively for www-data and to **html** directory.
3. Find all files recursively and change permission to 664 (you may need to execute this with **sudo**).
4. Find all directories recursively and change permission to 775 (you may need tho execute this with **sudo**).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not Working! I've Tried

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell everyone, every time I use Word *Chat* it says 403 access denied but when I removed this word it is working perfectly.

I don't know what was the error with this word